# What does ":=" do?

Tags: operators, colon-equals

I've seen `:=` used in several code samples, but never with an accompanying explanation. It's not exactly possible to google its use without knowing the proper name for it.

What does it do?

Comment: In what language?

Comment: You normally use `:=` when you define something, to separate it from regular variable changes.. What programming language are we talking about?

Comment: PL/SQL it is for assignment. But given a different language, that answer isn't guarenteed to hold true - so which languages was the example in?

Comment: To google something like this, spell it out and enclose it in quotes, like so: "colon equals"

Comment: I think Pascal's got this operator !

Comment: You can search for special symbols using [this](http://symbolhound.com) service.

Comment: The OP might have been referring to pseudocode, in which I've often seen `:=`.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equals_sign#In_computer_programming

> In computer programming languages, the equals sign typically denotes either a boolean operator to test equality of values (e.g. as in Pascal or Eiffel), which is consistent with the symbol's usage in mathematics, or an assignment operator (e.g. as in C-like languages). Languages making the former choice often use a colon-equals (:=) or ≔ to denote their assignment operator. Languages making the latter choice often use a double equals sign (==) to denote their boolean equality operator.

**Note:** I found this by searching for `colon equals operator`

Comment: Ironically, this answer is now above Wikipedia when searching for `colon equals operator`.

Comment: If we keep typing `colon equals operator`, we work magic on Google's SEO to make this the top result

Comment: That link looks old. Here's the updated link (I think), but the quote seems to be massively changed since then and I can't track down the new quote exactly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science).

Comment: Smalltalk was also an influential language that used the colon equals operator for assignment.

Answer (score 54):

It's the **assignment operator** in Pascal and is often used in proofs and pseudo-code. It's the same thing as `=` in C-dialect languages.

Historically, computer science papers used `=` for equality comparisons and `←` for assignments. Pascal used `:=` to stand in for the hard-to-type left arrow. C went a different direction and instead decided on the `=` and `==` operators.

Answer (score 29):

In the statically typed language [Go](http://golang.org) `:=` is initialization and assignment in one step. It is done to allow for interpreted-like creation of variables in a compiled language.

```
// Creates and assigns
answer := 42

// Creates and assigns
var answer = 42
```

Answer (score 10):

Another interpretation from outside the world of programming languages comes from **Wolfram Mathworld**, et al:

*If A and B are equal by definition (i.e., A is defined as B), then this is written symbolically as A=B, A:=B, or sometimes A≜B.*

■ http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Defined.html

■ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182101/appropriate-notation-equiv-versus

Answer (score 6):

Some language uses `:=` to act as the assignment operator.

Comment: @Pacerier see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462322/the-forgotten-assignment-operator-and-the-commonplace as to why the answer to your question can be both "Yes" and "No".

Comment: @TigOldBitties, Good gotcha from Erwin down there.

Answer (score 3):

In a lot of CS books, it's used as the assignment operator, to differentiate from the equality operator `=`. In a lot of high level languages, though, assignment is `=` and equality is `==`.

Answer (score 1):

This is old (pascal) syntax for the assignment operator.  It would be used like so:

```
a := 45;
```

It may be in other languages as well, probably in a similar use.

Answer (score 1):

> A number of programming languages, most notably [Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(programming_language)) and [Ada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_(programming_language)), use a colon immediately followed by an equals sign (`:=`) as the [assignment operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)), to distinguish it from a single equals which is an equality test (C instead used a single equals as assignment, and a double equals as the equality test).

Reference: [Colon (punctuation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_(punctuation)#Programming_languages).

Answer (score 1):

In **Python**:

*Named Expressions* (`NAME := expr`) was introduced in Python 3.8. It allows for the assignment of variables within an expression that is currently being evaluated. The *colon equals operator* `:=` is sometimes called the *walrus operator* because, well, it looks like a walrus emoticon.

For example:

```py
if any((comment := line).startswith('#') for line in lines):
    print(f"First comment: {comment}")
else:
    print("There are no comments")
```

This would be invalid if you swapped the `:=` for `=`. Note the additional parentheses surrounding the named expression. Another example:

```py
# Compute partial sums in a list comprehension
total = 0
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
partial_sums = [total := total + v for v in values]
# [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
print(f"Total: {total}")  # Total: 15
```

Note that the variable `total` is *not local* to the comprehension (so too is `comment` from the first example). The `NAME` in a named expression cannot be a local variable within an expression, so, for example, `[i := 0 for i, j in stuff]` would be invalid, because `i` *is* local to the list comprehension.

I've taken examples from the PEP 572 document - it's a good read! I for one am looking forward to using Named Expressions, once my company upgrades from Python 3.6. Hope this was helpful!

Sources: [Towards Data Science Article](https://towardsdatascience.com/when-and-why-to-use-over-in-python-b91168875453) and [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/).

Answer (score 0):

It's like an arrow without using a less-than symbol <= so like everybody already said "assignment" operator. Bringing clarity to what is being set to where as opposed to the logical operator of equivalence.

In Mathematics it is like equals but A := B means A is defined as B, a triple bar equals can be used to say it's similar and equal by definition but not always the same thing.

Anyway I point to these other references that were probably in the minds of those that invented it, but it's really just that plane equals and less that equals were taken (or potentially easily confused with =<) and something new to define assignment was needed and that made the most sense.

Historical References: I first saw this in SmallTalk the original Object Language, of which SJ of Apple only copied the Windows part of and BG of Microsoft watered down from them further (single threaded). Eventually SJ in NeXT took the second  more important lesson from Xerox PARC in, which became Objective C.

Well anyway they just took colon-equals assiment operator from ALGOL 1958 which was later popularized by Pascal

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PARC_(company)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)

> Assignments typically allow a variable to hold different values at
>   different times during its life-span and scope. However, some
>   languages (primarily strictly functional) do not allow that kind of
>   "destructive" reassignment, as it might imply changes of non-local
>   state.
>   The purpose is to enforce referential transparency, i.e. functions
>   that do not depend on the state of some variable(s), but produce the
>   same results for a given set of parametric inputs at any point in
>   time.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency

Answer (score 0):

For VB.net,

a constructor (for this case, Me = this in Java):

```
Public ABC(int A, int B, int C){
Me.A = A;
Me.B = B;
Me.C = C;
}
```

when you create that object:

```
new ABC(C:=1, A:=2, B:=3)
```

Then, regardless of the order of the parameters, that ABC object has A=2, B=3, C=1

So, ya, very good practice for others to read your code effectively

Answer (score -1):

Colon-equals was used in Algol and its descendants such as Pascal and Ada because it is as close as ASCII gets to a left-arrow symbol.

The strange convention of using equals for assignment and double-equals for comparison was started with the C language.

In Prolog, there is no distinction between assignment and the equality test.

Comment: If they wanted it close to the left arrow, they could have used `<-` like Haskell did. They weren't trying to get close to the left arrow with `:=`, they were using the mathematical 'is defined as' operator:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Defined.html

Comment: Pedant alert:  <- in Haskell is not assignment.  Haskell does not have destructive assignment in the way of Pascal, Ada etc.  <- is part of the do-notation syntax for parameter substitution.  It is more analogous to the process of substituting values into parameters in a subroutine call.

Comment: @Michael Fair enough. You're right. My bad. Anyway, the point remains that if they were trying to imitate the left arrow, they would not have used `:=`, they would have used `<-`.