# PostgreSQL how to use bitwise operator |=

Tags: postgresql, bitwise-operators

I want to execute the following update query at PostgreSQL db but it does not work and gives syntax error.

Query as follows

```
update wl_user set role_bitmask= role_bitmask|=1 where email='faisal@gmail.com'
```

Problem seems to be with `|=` operator, does anybody have idea how to use |= operator in PostgreSQL?

Following is the error.

> ```
> [Err] ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer |= integer
> LINE 1: ...pdate wl_user set role_bitmask=role_bitmask|=1 where ...
>                                                              ^
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `role_bitmask= role_bitmask|=1` you must use `role_bitmask=role_bitmask|1` which also  makes some sense if you think what `|=` does and what `|` does.

To clarify: PostgreSQL has a lot of operators and allow you to define new operators. But in your case this does not matter for two reasons:

- The manual for [UPDATE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-update.html) says about the syntax (abbreviated): `UPDATE ... table ... SET column = { expression | DEFAULT }`. This means, that the `=` is mandatory and *not* any of the normal operators. Therefore there is no `|=` and no `&=` .
- Among all those extensible operators there is no assignment operator. Assignment is handled in a special way for each case. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462322/the-forgotten-assignment-operator-and-the-commonplace) for some hints.

Regarding your question: An expression like `role_bitmask= role_bitmask|=1` make eyebrows raise in every language :-)

**Summary**: You have to use the long form `... SET column = colum | bitmask`.