# Can I make a plpgsql function return an integer without using a variable?

Tags: postgresql, function, variables, parameters, plpgsql

Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get(param_id integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
SELECT col1 FROM TABLE WHERE id = param_id;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I would like to avoid a `DECLARE` just for this.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Yes you can. There is a number of ways.

#### 1) `RETURN (SELECT ...)`

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_1(_param_id integer)
  RETURNS integer
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN _param_id;
-- Or:
-- RETURN (SELECT col1 FROM tbl WHERE id = _param_id);
END
$func$;
```

#### 2) Use an `OUT` or `INOUT` parameter

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_2(_param_id integer, OUT _col1 integer)
-- RETURNS integer -- is optional noise in this case
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS  
$func$
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO _col1  col1 FROM tbl WHERE id = _param_id;

   -- also possible (currently), but discouraged:
   -- _col1 := col1 FROM tbl WHERE id = _param_id;
END
$func$;
```

[More  in the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING)

#### 3) (Ab)use `IN` parameter

Since **Postgres 9.0** you can also use **input parameters** as variables. [The release notes for 9.0:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/release-9-0.html)

> An input parameter now acts like a local variable initialized to the passed-in value.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_3(_param_id integer)
  RETURNS integer
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO _param_id  col1 FROM tbl WHERE id = _param_id;
   RETURN _param_id;

   -- also possible (currently), but discouraged:
   -- $1 := col1 FROM tbl WHERE id = $1;
   -- RETURN $1;
END
$func$;
```

Variants 2) and 3) *do use* a variable implicitly, but you don't have to `DECLARE` one explicitly (as requested).

#### 4) Use a `DEFAULT` value with an `INOUT` parameter

This is a bit of a special case. The function body can be empty.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_4(_param_id integer, INOUT _col1 integer = 123)
  RETURNS integer
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   -- You can assign some (other) value to _col1:
   -- SELECT INTO _col1  col1 FROM tbl WHERE id = _param_id;
   -- If you don't, the DEFAULT 123 will be returned.
END
$func$;
```

`INOUT _col1 integer = 123` is short notation for `INOUT _col1 integer DEFAULT 123`. See:

- [The forgotten assignment operator "=" and the commonplace ":="](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462322/the-forgotten-assignment-operator-and-the-commonplace/22001209#22001209)

#### 5) Use a plain [SQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html) instead

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_5(_param_id integer)
  RETURNS integer
  LANGUAGE sql AS
'SELECT col1 FROM tbl WHERE id = _param_id';
```

Or use use param reference `$1` instead of param name.

Variant 5) one uses plain single quotes for the function body. All the same. See:

- [What are '$$' used for in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144284/what-are-used-for-in-pl-pgsql/12172353#12172353)
- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3OTmY2yx) - demonstrating all (incl. call)