# PostgreSQL function does not return a value

Tags: postgresql, function

-- I can not understand where the error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_person_membership (IN person_urn CHARACTER VARYING)

   RETURNS TEXT  AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
result text;
urn ALIAS FOR $1;

BEGIN

SELECT INTO result pers.mx_groupmember FROM mt_person AS pers, mxt_recordheader AS rech
WHERE rech.primaryurn = 'urn'
AND rech.entitytype = 'person' 
AND rech.logicalserverprefix = 'EA'
AND rech.id = pers.id;
RETURN result;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
VOLATILE
COST 100
```

Comment: change `SELECT INTO result pers.mx_groupmember` to `SELECT pers.mx_groupmember into result `

Comment: also, you don't actually use the `person_urn` parameter in your query (neither its `urn` alias, which is completely unnecessary, because the parameter has a name already).

Comment: I suppose you should write `rech.primaryurn =urn`  instead of `rech.primaryurn ='urn'`

Comment: Thank's a lot Vao

Answer (score 1):

i simplified your query:

- For input you can use $1, this goes to direct your condition.
- You can return direct your result if you dont need anywhere else.

  > select * from get_person_membership('something');

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_person_membership (IN person_urn CHARACTER VARYING) 
RETURNS TEXT  AS
$BODY$

BEGIN

RETURN (select pers.mx_groupmember --returns single value
FROM mt_person AS pers, mxt_recordheader AS rech
WHERE rech.primaryurn = $1 --input value from person_urn 
AND rech.entitytype = 'person' 
AND rech.logicalserverprefix = 'EA'
AND rech.id = pers.id);

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
VOLATILE
COST 100
```

Comment: `return from`? (@_@)

Comment: same as `return (select pers.mx_groupmember 
FROM mt_person AS pers, mxt_recordheader AS rech
WHERE rech.primaryurn = $1 --input value from person_urn 
AND rech.entitytype = 'person' 
AND rech.logicalserverprefix = 'EA'
AND rech.id = pers.id)`  related link: [first solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169676/can-i-make-a-plpgsql-function-return-an-integer-without-using-a-variable)

Comment: I have never heard of `RETURN FROM` either. And don't found any [evidence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html) that it's supposed to work. But [apparently, it does](http://rextester.com/LDAQA89851) (with 9.5 at least).

Comment: I tested in 9.6 and indeed it works. I wonder why isn't it in the docs.

Comment: This is probably something like the assignment with `=` see [9.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-statements.html) vs. [9.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html): it was supported a long ago (before 9.3), but was considered a hidden feature (and a bad design, because it can be easily confused with the equality test). This syntax seems to conform (at least) to `PERFORM`, so it might eventually get added to the docs. But until then, this is an undocumented feature, and as such, it might change without prior notice. Use this syntax very carefully.

Comment: i changed query to @ErwinBrandstetter example.[return(select...)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8169928/7689902)

Answer (score 0):

No need for PL/pgSQL, a simple SQL function will do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_person_membership (IN person_urn CHARACTER VARYING)
   RETURNS TEXT  AS
$BODY$
  SELECT pers.mx_groupmember 
  FROM mt_person AS pers
    JOIN mxt_recordheader AS rech ON rech.id = pers.id
  WHERE rech.primaryurn = person_urn --<< input parameter
    AND rech.entitytype = 'person' 
    AND rech.logicalserverprefix = 'EA';
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;
```