# Is possible have different conditions for each row in a query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How I can select a set of rows where each row match a different condition?

**Example:**

Supposing I have a table with a column called name, I want the result ONLY IF the first row name matches 'A', the second row name matches 'B' and the third row name matches 'C'.

**Edit:**

I want to do this to work without a fixed size, but in a way I can define the sequence like `R`,`X`,`V`,`P`,`T` and it matches the sequence, each one in a row, but in the order.

Comment: Are you sure you mean row? as thats completely dependent on the order by if it exists?

Comment: @Chris Yes, completely dependent on the order because the order is high important in what I want to do, and yes, the order exists.

Comment: Is there a field  that defines the order? There is no "natural" order implied in SQL

Comment: Maybe i don't understand you problem very well. You can do this with using union. something like this: select * from tab where name=A union select * from tab where name=B union select * from tab where name=A

Comment: What RDBMS?  I"m thinking if you treat the query as a hierichal query then it MIGHT work.  (I like the question though)

Comment: @xQbert The RDBMS is PostgreSQL.

Comment: @alexm The real case a bit more complex than this, so call the order field as `position`.

Comment: @Renato: and what do you want to be returned? Only the first 3 rows which match your condition, or every row afterwards, or do you want every list of 3 rows matching that condition?

Comment: @DocBrown Every list of the 3 sequential rows that match the condition.

Comment: Well I'm out: I dont' know postgresql well enough: but just for consideration: could the values be rows in a separate table of N size?

Comment: Can you show some sample data and the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that You know how to provide a row number to your rows (ROW_NUMBER() in SQL Server, for instance), You can create a lookup (match) table and join on it. See below for explanation:

LookupTable:

```
RowNum    Value
1         A
2         B
3         C
```

Your SourceTable source table (assuming You already added RowNum to it-in case You didn't, just introduce subquery for it (or CTE for SQL Server 2005 or newer):

```
RowNum Name
-----------
1      A
2      B
3      C
4      D
```

Now You need to inner join LookupTable with your SourceTable on `LookupTable.RowNum = SourceTable.RowNum AND LookupTable.Name = SourceTable.Name`. Then do a left join of this result with LookupTable on RowNum only. If there is `LookupTable.RowNum IS NULL` in final result then You know that there is no complete match on at least one row.

Here is code for joins:

```
SELECT T.*, LT2.RowNum AS Matched 
FROM LookupTable LT2
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT ST.*
    FROM SourceTable ST
    INNER JOIN LookupTable LT ON LT.RowNum = ST.RowNum AND LT.Name = ST.Name
) T
    ON LT2.RowNum = T.RowNum
```

Result set of above query will contain rows with `Matched IS NULL` if row is not matching condition from LookupTable table.

Comment: I'm with problem getting the row numbers. It's possible create a window from a number to itself? Example: start the `row_number()` count when found 595 and restarting when find again?

Comment: @RenatoDinhaniConceição, I guess not... in SQL Server You can UPDATE your table with clustered index with variable: http://geekswithblogs.net/Rhames/archive/2008/10/28/calculating-running-totals-in-sql-server-2005---the-optimal.aspx ... But You can restart numbering on groups. Take a look at PARTITION BY in ROW_NUMBER or RANK at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx

Comment: I used part of your logic to do a function to solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can, but probably not in a way you would want:

if your table has a numeric id field, that is incremented with each row, you can self join that table 3 times (lets say as "a", "b" and "c") and use the join condition a.id + 1 = b.id and b.id + 1 = c.id and put you filter in a where clause like: a.name = 'A' AND b.name = 'B' AND c.name = 'C'

but don't expect performance ...

Comment: Only drawback (beside potential problem with performance) is that You have to change your query if the number of conditions change. Am I missing something obvious or this way query will not return set of 3 rows when all of them match, but it will return one row with columns from all 3 rows?

Comment: "but probably not in a way you would want" ... ;) ... you could create the query by some piece of code if it changes often, and yes, this will give you 1 row instead of 3 ... to solve the problem with the number of rows, you could select the row IDs, and fetch the corresponding single rows with a second query ... ugly, i know ...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do a sub query for each row, but it wouldn't perform well or scale well at all and would be hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

This may be close to what your after... but I need to know where you're getting your values for A, B, C etc...

```
Select [insert your fields here]
FROM
(Select T1.Name, T1.Age, RowNum as t1RowNum from T T1 order by name) T1O
Full Outer JOIN 
(Select T2.Name, T2.Age, RowNum as T2rowNum From T T2 order By name) T2O
ON T1O.T1RowNum+1 = T2O.T2RowNum
```

Comment: **Never use *, always define the fields.**