# Execute file with SQLExec containing $$ characters

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, ant

I've created a sql dump file using pg_dump. This export file contains functions which contain $$ characters. No problem to import the file with psql -f < filename>.

If want to import the file with ant using the SQLExec task, I get an exception like:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$"
```

Is there a way to import a file containing $$?

In the postgres Log it seems that the SQLExec tasks converts $$ to $ which the  causes the error.

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$" at character 87
STATEMENT:     CREATE FUNCTION process_create_servicenumber() RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $ BEGIN IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN RETURN OLD

Here my method

```
protected void importNewDbFromDumpFile() {

    final class SqlExecuter extends SQLExec {
        public SqlExecuter() {
            Project project = new Project();
            project.init();
            setProject(project);
            setTaskType("sql");
            setTaskName("sql");
        }
    }
    try {
        SqlExecuter executer = new SqlExecuter();
        executer.setSrc(new File(dbDumpFileLocation));
        executer.setClasspath(createClasspath());
        executer.setEscapeProcessing(true);
        executer.setDriver("org.postgresql.Driver");
        executer.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test");
        executer.setPassword("test");
        executer.setUserid("manager");
        executer.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.info("Exception importing database ...", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include some sample data? `$$` is usually used for [dollar quoting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) strings.

Comment: CREATE FUNCTION time_to_sec(timepoint timestamp with time zone) RETURNS bigint
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
DECLARE
  seconds bigint;
  secondsFromEpoch bigint;
  secondsFromMidnight bigint;
BEGIN
  secondsFromEpoch = EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM timepoint)::bigint;
  secondsFromMidnight = EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::date)::bigint;
  seconds = secondsFromEpoch - secondsFromMidnight;
  return seconds;
END;
$$;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$$` is just the bare minimum for [**dollar-quoting**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING). Make it (much!) less likely to conflict with strings in the enclosed literal by putting a string between the dollars:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION time_to_sec(timepoint timestamp with time zone)
  RETURNS bigint LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
 seconds bigint;
 secondsFromEpoch bigint;
 secondsFromMidnight bigint;
BEGIN
 secondsFromEpoch = EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM timepoint)::bigint;
 secondsFromMidnight = EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::date)::bigint;
 seconds = secondsFromEpoch - secondsFromMidnight;
 return seconds;
END;
$BODY$;
```

#### More advice

- The assignment operator in plpgsql is `:=`. `=`  is undocumented and may go away in future releases. More under this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7462322/939860).
- Use [`CURRENT_DATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) instead of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::date`.
- It is allowed, but I would advise not to use mixed case parameter names in plpgsql. They are case insensitive.
- Most importantly, **simplify**:

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION time_to_sec2(timepoint timestamp with time zone)
    RETURNS bigint LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE AS
  $BODY$
  BEGIN
      RETURN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM timepoint - current_date)::bigint;
  END;
  $BODY$;
  ```

  Or even:

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION time_to_sec3(timepoint timestamp with time zone)
    RETURNS bigint LANGUAGE sql AS
  $BODY$
      SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM timepoint - current_date)::bigint;
  $BODY$;
  ```
- Can be declared [`STABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html)!

> Also note that the current_timestamp family of functions qualify as
>   stable, since their values do not change within a transaction.

- There is also the closely related function [`age()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html) in PostgreSQL doing almost, but not quite, the same: it returns a "symbolic" result with standard-years and months. Therefore, expression with `age()` can yield different results for longer periods of time.

These are all equivalent - except for the last two deviating with longer periods of time:

```
WITH x(t) AS (VALUES ('2012-07-20 03:51:26+02'::timestamptz))
SELECT time_to_sec(t)  AS t1
      ,time_to_sec2(t) AS t2
      ,time_to_sec3(t) AS t3
      ,EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM t - current_date)::bigint AS t4
      ,EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM age(t, current_date))::bigint AS t5 -- deviates
      ,EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM age(t))::bigint * -1  AS t6  -- deviates
FROM   x;
```

---

As to the original question: this PostgreSQL error message does not necessarily mean the problem is with the dollar sign:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "$"

Most of the time it's a missing `;` before that line. Or maybe an un-escaped special characters in XML, like `< > &` ? The dollar sign `$` should be fine. But I am no expert with ant. There should be more context in the PostgreSQL log.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. In the logs it seems that $$ is converted to $ by the SQLExec task, that seems to be the root of the error.