# Interval (days) in PostgreSQL with two parameters

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-range

In this query:

`Select * from table where future_date - CURRENT_DATE <= '10';`

It returns the interval of 10 days or less.

How to add two parameters? Example:

```
Select * from table where future_date - CURRENT_DATE <= '10' AND >= '30';
```

I already tried:

```
Select * from table where future_date - CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN '10' AND '30'
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: It would be essential to disclose the data type of `future_date` and (as always) your Postgres version. You should also clarify if you want to cover an interval of 20, 21 or 40 / 41 days - calendar days? Your examples are contradicting. `But it doesn't work.` is not helping. In what way does it not work? My educated guess: an error message for the first try (you should include error messages in the Q), and *no rows* for the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   future_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE + '10 days'::INTERVAL AND CURRENT_DATE + '30 days'::INTERVAL
```

Comment: This answer is wrong in almost every aspect. `CURRENT_DATE`  is just as stable as `now()`, an index can very well be used for `CURRENT_DATE`, just not for expressions that are not sargable. Also, suggesting `BETWEEN .. AND ..` for a `timestamp` column is a bad idea to say the least, and for a `date` column the expression does not make much sense and is misleading. Without any proper explanation this answer is a *trap*.

Answer (score 10):

#### Explanation

Your first *example* is syntactical nonsense, but your **second is valid** and would (mostly) work as expected if your column was actually a `date` like the column name suggests:

```
Select * from table where future_date - CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN '10' AND '30'
```

The result of the expression `future_date - CURRENT_DATE` depends on the actual, undisclosed **data type** of `future_date`.

If `future_date` is a [**`date`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html), the result of `future_date - CURRENT_DATE` is an `integer` number signifying the difference in days, and your untyped **string literals** `'10'` and `'30'` are cast to `integer` per assignment cast: the query is *valid* (even if inefficient) and covers a range of 21 days (not 20).

If `future_date` is a [**`timestamp`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) ([or `timestamptz`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html)), the result is an `interval` signifying a time interval. It would be odd but legal to use `CURRENT_DATE` in this context. The value is coerced to `timestamp` (or `timestamptz`) assuming 00:00 hours of the day.

However, your untyped string literals are now cast to `interval` and without any given time unit, [an `integer` number means **seconds** by default](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT), so the predicate effectively selects a narrow time frame of 10 to 30 seconds from *now*.

See for yourself:

```
SELECT '10'::interval

interval
---------
'00:00:10'
```

To **clarify misinformation**: `CURRENT_DATE` is just fine. It's a standard SQL function without parentheses for legacy reasons. Used to be implemented as `now()::date` internally in Postgres. Both are `STABLE` functions (so "runtime constants"). The additional problem with your expression: it's very inefficient because it's **not [sargable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sargable)**.

### Proper solution

For a **`date`** column:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  future_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE + 10
                       AND CURRENT_DATE + 30;  -- 21 days (!)
```

You can just **add `integer` to `date`** to add / subtract days.

This gives you a range of 21 (not 20!) days because `BETWEEN` **includes** lower and upper bound. Typically, you'd want to include the lower but **exclude** the upper bound.

For a **`timestamp`**  or **`timestamptz`** column:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  future_date >= now() + interval '10 days'
AND    future_date <  now() + interval '30 days';  -- 20 days (!)
```

This covers a time frame of 20 days (!) spread out across 21 calendar days (!) unless you start at midnight *exactly*, in which case exactly 20 calendar days are covered completely.

Typically, you'd want to work with **calendar days as bounds**:

```
... 
WHERE  future_date >= (CURRENT_DATE + 10)
AND    future_date <  (CURRENT_DATE + 30);
```

Or either of these expressions for `timestamp` or `timestamptz`:

```
now()::date               + interval '10 days'  -- returns timestamp
CURRENT_DATE              + interval '10 days'  -- returns timestamp
date_trunc('day', now())  + interval '10 days'  -- returns timestamptz
```

The data type is cast to the the type of `future_date`, so it works for either type.

Note that a *date* is defined by its time zone. So these expressions depend on the current `timezone` setting of the session.

It should be evident by now, why `BETWEEN .. AND ..` is **typically *wrong*** with timestamps. Mostly, you want to *include* the lower bound and *exclude* the upper. `BETWEEN .. AND ..` would include `00:00` of the next day in the last example, thus opening a corner case for a 21st day.

Related:

- [Subtract hours from the now() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894296/subtract-hours-from-the-now-function/30896121#30896121)
- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Comment: I vaguely remember `CURRENT_DATE` was intended to show wall clock time on each invocation, at least in the past. Was it so or am I confusing it with something else?

Comment: @Quassnoi: You may be thinking of `transaction_timestamp()`, 
`statement_timestamp()` or  `clock_timestamp()` which would fit that profile. The `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` family of functions has `STABLE` function volatility, i.e. return the same value within the same transaction. [Details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) Related answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28573737/939860, http://stackoverflow.com/a/11714281/939860