# SQL converting time difference to int

Tags: sql, postgresql

I type `select (signup_date - CURRENT_DATE) from table`

I get a result like `{ "days": -76, "hours": -3 }`

How do I transform it to int? So that I can compare it to other numbers.
For example, if `signup_date - CURRENT_DATE > 5`, then do something

Also, what format is that? `{ "days": -76, "hours": -3 }`

Comment: "How do I transform it to int? So that I can compare it to other numbers." -- Do it the other way. Cast your integers to intervals. You can compare intervals with intervals in Postgres. Something like `(<your number> || ' seconds')::interval` will do such a cast, if the number represents seconds. But you can use any other unit as well.

Comment: Declare the exact data type of your input, what your desired integer number shall represent, and your version of Postgres.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

If `signup_date` as type `date` like the name suggests, the expression would indeed yield an `integer` signifying the number of days ([`date - date → integer`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#OPERATORS-DATETIME-TABLE)):

```
SELECT signup_date - CURRENT_DATE;
```

But if `signup_date` is type `timestamp` or `timestamptz`, you get an [`interval`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-TABLE).

Then you can extract all kinds of integer numbers with [`extract()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT). You just have to define what you need exactly.

See:

- [How do I determine the last day of the previous month using PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944721/how-do-i-determine-the-last-day-of-the-previous-month-using-postgresql/8945281#8945281)
- [Interval (days) in PostgreSQL with two parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123409/interval-days-in-postgresql-with-two-parameters/31127978#31127978)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select rows, then I would recommend:

```
select . . .
from table t
where signup_date > current_date + interval '5 day';
```

It seems really weird to have future signup dates, so I suspect you want:

```
select . . .
from table t
where signup_date > current_date - interval '5 day';
```

If you want to assign a column a value you can use `case`.  For instance:

```
select (case when signup_date > current-date - interval '5 day'
             then 'recent' else 'old'
        end)
from table;
```