# Postgresql regex in tsvector update

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, postgresql-9.0, tsvector

I have the following update trigger for a tsvector column

```
CREATE TRIGGER tsvector_user_update
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE 
tsvector_update_trigger(user_tsv, 'pg_catalog.english', firstname, surname, email, card_id);
```

This works fine, however my card_id column (text) contains a pre-amble that the user is not aware of (it is added after the card is scanned), so I would like to strip out the pre-amble when the tsvector value is generated, I have tried the trigger function as a start

```
CREATE FUNCTION user_change_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
NEW.user_tsv = setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(NEW.firstname,'')), 'A') ||
    setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(NEW.surname,'')), 'A') ||
    setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(REGEXP_REPLACE(NEW.card_id, '^\d+PRE', ''),'')), 'B') ||
    setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(NEW.email,'')), 'C');
    return new;
END

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tsvectorupdate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON users FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE user_change_trigger();
```

Which executes, but I get the following:

```
WARNING:  nonstandard use of escape in a string literal
```

And no updated tsvector

The pre-amble is an integer followed by 'PRE'.

(PostgreSQL 9.0)

Comment: Should be obvious that example values are in order. What do you have and what do you want as result from `regexp_replace()`. And "without success" doesn't seem to be an error message I know of PostgreSQL ..

Comment: the regex is not really relevent, I really wanted to know if it possible to modify the column contents before it is put into the tsvector_update_trigger method, and as you have stated below this is not possible, I need to write a trigger function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Basic trigger design

The problem is of principal nature. In PostgreSQL you create a **trigger function** that does the work. I don't see your trigger function in the question.

Then you create a **trigger** which makes use of this function. You can only pass *constants* to a trigger function. Consider this quote from [the manual about `CREATE TRIGGER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html)

> *function_name*
>
> A user-supplied function that is declared as **taking no arguments** and
>   returning type trigger, which is executed when the trigger fires.
>
> *arguments*
>
> An optional comma-separated list of arguments to be provided to the
>   function when the trigger is executed. The **arguments are literal
>   string constants**. Simple names and numeric constants can be written
>   here, too, but they will all be converted to strings. Please check the
>   description of the implementation language of the trigger function to
>   find out how these arguments can be accessed within the function; it
>   might be different from normal function arguments.

Bold emphasis mine.

Use `NEW` to access the column values inside the trigger function. You don't need to pass them as arguments. Get a grip on the basic concept first. [Start here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/triggers.html)

#### `regexp_replace()`

Use:

```
regexp_replace(card_id, '^\d+PRE', '')
```

.. since the leading characters are supposed to be digits only (and at least one of them).

#### Proper trigger & function

The following test case *works for me* on PostgreSQL 9.1.6. Your version looks basically good to me, I only made minor changes. But keep reading ...

Create test environment (will be rolled back at the end):

```
BEGIN;
CREATE SCHEMA test;
SET search_path = test;

CREATE TABLE users (
    users_id serial primary key
   ,firstname text
   ,surname text
   ,card_id text
   ,email text
   ,user_tsv tsvector
   );
```

Trigger function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION user_change_trigger()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN

NEW.user_tsv :=
   setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(NEW.firstname,'')), 'A')
|| setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(NEW.surname,'')), 'A')
|| setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(regexp_replace(NEW.card_id, '^\d+PRE', ''),'')), 'B')
|| setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(NEW.email,'')), 'C');

RETURN NEW;
END

$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The [assignment operator of plpgsql is **`:=`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462322/the-forgotten-assignment-operator-and-the-commonplace) - unlike SQL where `=` is used.

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tsvectorupdate
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE user_change_trigger();
```

Tests:

```
INSERT INTO users (firstname, surname, card_id, email)
VALUES ('Erwin', 'Brandstetter', '123PRE456', 'foo@dummy.org')
RETURNING *;

-- looks good!

UPDATE users SET firstname = 'Walter' WHERE TRUE
RETURNING *;

-- looks good, too!
```

Clean up:

```
ROLLBACK;
```

#### `standard_conforming_strings`

Explore your setting of [`standard_conforming_strings`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS). The WARNING suggests that you don't have this setting on, which would require that you double the backslash in:

```
'^\\d+PRE'
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the docs and correcting regex, after some reading up I have attempted to write a trigger function (see updated question), but I am a plpgsql novice so any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: @DaveB: I added some more to my answer.

Comment: Thank you Erwin, I set standard_conforming_strings = 1 and it works as you say. Excellent answer :)