# Data type error on prepared execution plan

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-injection, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have the below error, this error only happens in the second execution cause the planning cache

> ```
> ERROR: el tipo del parámetro 11 (character varying) no coincide aquel con que fue preparado el plan (text)
> Where: PL/pgSQL function graficar(character varying,character varying,character varying) line 22 at asignación
> ```

It means that variables or values in the below function don't match `character varying` / `text` in line 22. There is no explicit text value defined, I suppose it happens in the concatenation of the query string:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION graficar(tabla character varying, columna character varying, valor character varying) RETURNS SETOF resultado As $$
    DECLARE
        r resultado;
        i record;
        query character varying = '';
        limite character varying = '';
    BEGIN
    IF columna <> '' THEN
       limite = ' where ' || columna || ' =  $1';
    END IF;

        IF tabla = 'edad' THEN
            query =   'WITH ranges AS ( SELECT (ten*10)::text ||''-''||(ten*10+9)::text AS range, ten*10 AS r_min, ten*10+9 AS r_max FROM generate_series(0,9) AS t(ten)) SELECT r.range as nombre, count(s.*) as cuenta FROM ranges r  LEFT JOIN ( select * from persona '|| limite ||' ) as s ON  s.edad BETWEEN r.r_min AND r.r_max GROUP BY r.range HAVING range NOT IN (''0-9'') ORDER BY r.range;';
        ELSEIF tabla = 'ingreso' THEN
           query =   'WITH ranges AS ( SELECT (ten*10)::text|| ''-''||((ten*10+199))::text || '' mil'' AS range, ten*10/1000 AS r_min, (ten*10+199999)/1000 AS r_max FROM generate_series(0,(SELECT max(ingreso)/10000 FROM persona), 20) AS t(ten)) SELECT r.range as nombre, count(s.*) as cuenta FROM ranges r  LEFT JOIN ( select * from persona '|| limite ||' ) as s ON s.ingreso BETWEEN r.r_min AND r.r_max GROUP BY r.range  ORDER BY r.range;';
        ELSE
            query = 'select p.nombre, count( e.* ) as cuenta from ' || tabla::regclass ||' p left join ( select * from persona ' || limite ||' ) as e on p.nombre = e.'|| tabla::regclass ||' group by p.nombre ';
    END IF;

    FOR i IN EXECUTE query USING valor LOOP  -- I DONT KNOW EXACTLY WHERE LINE 22 I SUPOSSE IS THIS
        r = (i.nombre, i.cuenta);
        RETURN NEXT r;
    END LOOP;
    END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem, but for assignment you'll want to use `:=` instead of `=`.  `=` is generally used to test equality in PL/PGSQL.

Comment: I change = for :=, but the problem persist. I think the root of the problem in this part "query =   'WITH ranges AS ( SELECT (ten*10)::text ||..." cause the casting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION graficar(tabla text, columna text, valor text)
  RETURNS SETOF resultado As
$func$
DECLARE
   _query text;
   limite text := '';
BEGIN
IF columna <> '' THEN
   limite := format(' AND %I = %L', columna, valor); -- properly escaped
END IF;

_query :=
   CASE tabla
   WHEN 'edad' THEN
   $q$WITH ranges AS (
         SELECT concat(ten, '0-', ten, '9') AS range
               ,ten*10 AS r_min, ten*10+9 AS r_max
         FROM   generate_series(1,9) ten)
      SELECT r.range AS nombre, count(p.*)::int AS cuenta
      FROM   ranges       r
      LEFT   JOIN persona p ON p.edad BETWEEN r.r_min AND r.r_max$q$
      || limite || '
      GROUP  BY r.range
      ORDER  BY r.range'

   WHEN 'ingreso' THEN
   $q$WITH ranges AS (
         SELECT concat(ten, '0-', ten*10 + 199, ' mil') AS range
               ,ten*10/1000 AS r_min, (ten*10+199999)/1000 AS r_max
         FROM   generate_series(0,(SELECT max(ingreso)/10000 FROM persona)
                                                             , 20) AS ten)
      SELECT r.range AS nombre, count(p.*)::int AS cuenta
      FROM   ranges r
      LEFT   JOIN persona p ON p.ingreso BETWEEN r.r_min AND r.r_max$q$
      || limite || '
      GROUP  BY r.range
      ORDER  BY r.range'

   ELSE
      format(
   $q$SELECT t.nombre, count(p.*)::int AS cuenta
      FROM   %1$I t
      LEFT   JOIN persona p on p.%1$I = t.nombre$q$ || limite || '
      GROUP  BY t.nombre'
      , tabla)
   END;

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE _query;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### Major points:

- Using `text` in place of `character varying` for simplicity.
- Using [`concat()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) for easier formatting. Requires Postgres 9.1+.
- Use a **human-readable format**! The strings you posted can hardly be maintained.
- Generating numbers starting from `1` for the first case, since you exclude the case for `0` at the end anyway. Consequently, trim the now redundant `HAVING` clause.
- The [assignment operator in plpgsql is `:=`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462322/the-forgotten-assignment-operator-and-the-commonplace) not `=` - which generally works, but is an undocumented feature that may go away in future versions.
- Make proper use of dollar quotes.
- Use a simple [`RETURN QUERY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) in place of the whole `LOOP` construct at the end.
- Don't use `query` as variable name, it is a reserved word in plpgsql. Substituted `_query` instead.
- To avoid a potential **type mismatch** as [described by @Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18966464/939860), provide `valor` as string literal in the query. This is a rare exception to the rule! Normally, the superior approach is to pass values with the `USING` clause like you had it. But to provide for a range of potentially varying types, your best choice is to supply an untyped string literal that can be coerced to *any* type automatically. This way, the expression remains [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) and any index potentially existing for the column can be used.
- Avoid SQL injection by properly escaping *all* identifiers and strings. I am using `format()` mostly. Requires Postgres 9.1+. [Details in this related answer on dba.SE.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries/49718#49718)

Comment: THANKS!!! I just added ::text in this part: q$SELECT t.nombre:text, count(p.*)::int AS cuenta

Answer (score 1):

Since `EXECUTE` is supposed to re-plan each time it's run, the error shouldn't come from a plan cache problem.

So aside from that, there seems to be two potential errors in this function:

1) when `columna<>''` is false, there is no parameter in the dynamic query, yet the `EXECUTE` tries to submit a value with `USING valor`.

2) when `columna<>''` is true, it's comparing this column with a value of type `character varying` even if the column is of a type that can't be implicitly compared to this value. Presumably this would need an explicit cast to text:

```
limite = ' where ' || columna || '::text =  $1';
```

and have the `valor` parameter be of type `text` (or keep the `character varying` but use the `CAST` syntax).

Comment: 1) Providing values in the `USING` clause that are not used is not a problem. 2) may be an issue, though. If `columna` can be of an incompatible type, providing a *string literal* instead of the typed value might be the better alternative. This way the resulting expression remains sargable. I'll provide an answer.