# Using a Stored Procedure in a View with Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, correlated-subquery

I have been trying to create a View where one of the column pending_amount gets its value as a result of a stored procedure execution.

The stored procedure is **pending_stock(int,int)** and returns an integer. The view is created successfully but when i try to perform any query like select on the this view it takes ever to return a value.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_production_parts AS 
SELECT p.part_id, p.min_amount, gp.part_num, gp.description
     , p.quantity_available
     , p.quantity_total - p.quantity_available AS quantity_alloc
     , p.quantity_total
     , (SELECT pending_stock(p.part_id, 0) AS pending_stock) AS pending_amount
     , p.production_run
     , CASE
           WHEN ppur.purchased_part_id IS NOT NULL THEN true
           ELSE false
       END AS is_purchased_part, ppur.purchased_part_id, p.store_move_type_id
     , gp.part_status_id, p.default_location
     , COALESCE(pwoh.part_work_order_hold_id, 0) AS part_work_order_hold_id
   FROM general_part gp
   JOIN part p ON gp.part_id = p.part_id
   LEFT JOIN purchased_part ppur ON ppur.part_id = p.part_id
   LEFT JOIN part_work_order_hold pwoh ON pwoh.part_id = p.part_id
  ORDER BY gp.part_num;
```

Can a stored procedure be used in a view? If used, Is my declaration correct?

Find the [result from of this query at explain.depesz.com](http://explain.depesz.com/s/elr):

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(*) FROM view_production_parts
```

I am using Postgres 8.4.
Function definition for `pending_stock(int,int)`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pending_stock(var_part_id integer
                                       , var_pattern_id integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
declare
    r record;
    var_qty_expected integer;
    var_qty_moved_to_stock integer;
    var_total_stock_moved_out integer;
    var_actual_qty integer;

begin

var_total_stock_moved_out := 0;
var_qty_expected := 0;

   for r in
      select work_order_id,quantity_expected
      from view_work_orders
      where part_id = var_part_id and open = 'TRUE'
      and quantity_allocated is null and quantity_expected >= quantity_actual

   loop
      var_qty_expected = var_qty_expected + r.quantity_expected;

      select sum(quantity) from view_work_order_move_parts_details
      where source_work_order_id = r.work_order_id
      and part_id = var_part_id into var_qty_moved_to_stock;

      if var_qty_moved_to_stock is null then
         var_qty_moved_to_stock = 0;
      end if;

      var_total_stock_moved_out = var_total_stock_moved_out
                                + var_qty_moved_to_stock;
   end loop;

   var_actual_qty := var_qty_expected - var_total_stock_moved_out;

   if var_actual_qty > 0 then
      return var_actual_qty;
   else
      return 0;
   end if;
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE STRICT
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION pending_stock(integer, integer) OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: @Erwin:  I am relatively new to Stack overflow. SO my format might be way of course. You made the question more readable and thanks a lot. I have updated the end of the function declaration as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### View

You don't need a subquery for the function call. And you can simplify some other minor details:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_production_parts AS 
SELECT  p.part_id, p.min_amount
      , gp.part_num, gp.description, p.quantity_available
      , p.quantity_total - p.quantity_available AS quantity_alloc
      , p.quantity_total
      , pending_stock(gp.part_id, 0) AS pending_amount
      , p.production_run
      ,(ppur.purchased_part_id IS NOT NULL) AS is_purchased_part
      , ppur.purchased_part_id, p.store_move_type_id, gp.part_status_id
      , p.default_location
      , COALESCE(pwoh.part_work_order_hold_id, 0) AS part_work_order_hold_id
FROM    general_part              gp
JOIN    part                      p    USING (part_id)
LEFT    JOIN purchased_part       ppur USING (part_id)
LEFT    JOIN part_work_order_hold pwoh USING (part_id)
ORDER   BY gp.part_num;
```

Other than that the VIEW definition looks fine.

### Function

Can be largely simplified:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pending_stock(var_part_id integer
                                       , var_pattern_id integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$func$
DECLARE
    r record;
    var_qty_expected            integer   := 0;
    var_total_stock_moved_out   integer   := 0;
BEGIN
   FOR r IN
      SELECT work_order_id, quantity_expected
      FROM   view_work_orders
      WHERE  part_id = var_part_id
      AND    open = 'TRUE'  -- A string instead of a boolean?
      AND    quantity_allocated IS NULL
      AND    quantity_expected >= quantity_actual
   LOOP
      var_qty_expected := var_qty_expected + r.quantity_expected;

      SELECT var_total_stock_moved_out + COALESCE(sum(quantity), 0)
      FROM   view_work_order_move_parts_details
      WHERE  source_work_order_id = r.work_order_id
      AND    part_id = var_part_id
      INTO   var_total_stock_moved_out;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN GREATEST(var_qty_expected - var_total_stock_moved_out, 0);
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

#### Major points

- Generally, assignments are comparatively expensive in plpgsql. Every assignment is executed with a (very simple and fast) `SELECT` statement internally. Try to use fewer of them.
- You can init variables at declaration time. No need for another statement.
- [The assignment operator in plpgsql is `:=`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462322/the-forgotten-assignment-operator-and-the-commonplace). `=` works, but is undocumented.
- Use [`COALESCE()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to catch `NULL` values.
- The function parameter `var_pattern_id` is never used. This is probably not the full function definition.
- The whole final part can be replaced with a single statement using [`GREATEST`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST)

### Superior query

Now, this cleaned up function will be a bit faster, but not much. Your whole design of looping repeatedly is **extremely inefficient**. It results in correlated subqueries that loop through correlated subqueries yet again. Performance nightmare.

Recast the problem as set-based operation to make it faster. Well, ***a lot*** faster.

```sql
SELECT e.part_id
      ,GREATEST(COALESCE(sum(e.quantity_expected), 0)
              - COALESCE(sum(m.total_stock_moved_out), 0), 0)
FROM   view_work_orders e
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT source_work_order_id       AS work_order_id
         ,COALESCE(sum(quantity), 0) AS total_stock_moved_out
   FROM   view_work_order_move_parts_details
   WHERE  part_id = var_part_id
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) m USING (work_order_id)
WHERE  e.part_id            =  var_part_id
AND    e.open               =  'TRUE'
AND    e.quantity_allocated IS NULL
AND    e.quantity_expected  >= e.quantity_actual
GROUP  BY 1;
```

#### Superior view

Integrate this into the original query / view:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_production_parts AS 
SELECT p.part_id, p.min_amount
      ,gp.part_num, gp.description, p.quantity_available
      ,p.quantity_total - p.quantity_available AS quantity_alloc
      ,p.quantity_total
      ,x.pending_amount
      ,p.production_run
      ,(ppur.purchased_part_id IS NOT NULL) AS is_purchased_part
      ,ppur.purchased_part_id, p.store_move_type_id, gp.part_status_id
      ,p.default_location
      ,COALESCE(pwoh.part_work_order_hold_id, 0) AS part_work_order_hold_id
FROM   general_part              gp
JOIN   part                      p    USING (part_id)
LEFT   JOIN purchased_part       ppur USING (part_id)
LEFT   JOIN part_work_order_hold pwoh USING (part_id)
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT e.part_id
         ,GREATEST(COALESCE(sum(e.quantity_expected), 0)
                 - COALESCE(sum(m.total_stock_moved_out), 0)
                   , 0) AS pending_amount
   FROM   view_work_orders e
   LEFT   JOIN (
      SELECT source_work_order_id AS work_order_id
            ,sum(quantity)        AS total_stock_moved_out
      FROM   view_work_order_move_parts_details
      WHERE  part_id = var_part_id
      GROUP  BY 1
      ) m USING (work_order_id)
   WHERE  e.part_id            =  var_part_id
   AND    e.open               =  'TRUE'
   AND    e.quantity_allocated IS NULL
   AND    e.quantity_expected  >= e.quantity_actual
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) x USING (part_id)
ORDER  BY gp.part_num;
```

Untested, obviously.

Comment: Firstly Thanks a lot for the help. Even after making the changes suggested by you still i face the same problem. View is created successfully but when i just perform a query **select count(*) from view_production_parts** it takes ages to get the result. It should return around 26000 row count.

Comment: @Ram: Run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(*) FROM  view_production_parts`, paste the output to http://explain.depesz.com/ and *edit* (left under your question) your question with the link. Also please supply the complete function definition in your question and your version of Postgres.

Comment: Please find the edited post and hope it provides all the details you are looking for. I am new to Databases so my queries may seem bit naive. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: I am really pleased by your suggestions. The stored procedure i provided above isn't a complete one, i pasted the relevant part of the code that is of concern. I realized my mistakes and it helped me a lot. I now know why the view is slow. U provided me with a valuable insight. Thanks a lot