# CentOS 7, PostgreSQL 9.2.18 - Can't access $libdir/postgis-2.0

Tags: postgresql, centos, postgis, redhat, system-administration

this is my first question on StackOverflow, hope I found some answers :D

I'm currently working on a database that I got to restore using Postgis. I installed that extension, but Postgres is unable to find it.

I'm working on a VM based on CentOS 7 that my boss gave me to troubleshoot this issue. He told me the VM, for prod purposes, had to use Postgre 9.2, that I installed using the following command :

```
yum install https://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/postgresql92-postgresql/9.2.18/1.el7/x86_64/postgresql92-postgresql-9.2.18-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
https://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/postgresql92-postgresql/9.2.18/1.el7/x86_64/postgresql92-postgresql-contrib-9.2.18-1.el7.x86_64.rpm 
https://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/postgresql92-postgresql/9.2.18/1.el7/x86_64/postgresql92-postgresql-libs-9.2.18-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
https://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/postgresql92-postgresql/9.2.18/1.el7/x86_64/postgresql92-postgresql-server-9.2.18-1.el7.x86_64.rpm 
https://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/postgresql92/1.1/20.el7/x86_64/postgresql92-runtime-1.1-20.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Next I created a symlink for libpq :

```
ln -s /opt/rh/postgresql92/root/usr/lib64/libpq.so.postgresql92-5 /lib64/libpq.so.postgresql92-5
```

And added the PATH in the /etc/profile :

```
# Rajout du PATH pour postgres
PATH=$PATH:/opt/rh/postgresql92/root/usr/bin
```

Next I created folder for the datas to be saved here :

```
[root@bdx-re-postgres02 lib64]# ll /app/data/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 4 postgres postgres 29 31 mai   15:40 postgres
[root@bdx-re-postgres02 lib64]# ll /app/data/postgres/
total 4
drwx------. 15 postgres postgres 4096  1 juin  11:01 data
drwxr-xr-x.  3 postgres postgres   18 31 mai   16:31 tbs
[root@bdx-re-postgres02 lib64]# ll /app/data/postgres/data/
total 48
drwx------. 5 postgres postgres    41 31 mai   16:42 base
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres  4096  1 juin  11:01 global
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres    18 31 mai   16:42 pg_clog
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres  4232 31 mai   16:42 pg_hba.conf
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres  1636 31 mai   16:42 pg_ident.conf
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres    58  1 juin  00:00 pg_log
drwx------. 4 postgres postgres    36 31 mai   16:42 pg_multixact
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres    18  1 juin  11:01 pg_notify
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres     6 31 mai   16:42 pg_serial
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres     6 31 mai   16:42 pg_snapshots
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres    25  1 juin  11:52 pg_stat_tmp
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres    18 31 mai   16:42 pg_subtrans
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres    19 31 mai   16:46 pg_tblspc
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres     6 31 mai   16:42 pg_twophase
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres     4 31 mai   16:42 PG_VERSION
drwx------. 3 postgres postgres    60 31 mai   16:42 pg_xlog
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 19834 31 mai   16:42 postgresql.conf
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres    86  1 juin  11:01 postmaster.opts
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres    95  1 juin  11:01 postmaster.pid
[root@bdx-re-postgres02 lib64]# ll /app/data/postgres/tbs/
total 0
drwx------. 3 postgres postgres 30 31 mai   16:46 DV3F
[root@bdx-re-postgres02 lib64]#
```

And I created the tablespaces with a symink in /app/data/psotgres with the right permissions for postgres user :

```
[root@bdx-re-postgres02 lib64]# ll /var/lib/pgsql/9.2/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres 22 31 mai   16:04 tbs -> /app/data/postgres/tbs
[root@bdx-re-postgres02 lib64]# ll /app/data/postgres/tbs/
total 0
drwx------. 3 postgres postgres 30 31 mai   16:46 DV3F
[root@bdx-re-postgres02 lib64]#
```

Next I modified the /usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql92-postgresql.service file to add the database folder for PGDATA :

```
# Location of database directory
#Environment=PGDATA=/opt/rh/postgresql92/root/var/lib/pgsql/data
Environment=PGDATA=/app/data/postgres/data
```

And I added to repo my boss told me for installing Postgis :

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo http://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/

yum install postgis
```

This is where the troubles begin. When I check for postgis files, I have the following :

```
    [root@bdx-re-postgres02 lib64]# ll /usr/share/pgsql/contrib/postgis-2.0
total 5060
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    1239  2 avril  2016 legacy_gist.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    2508  2 avril  2016 legacy_minimal.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   54418  2 avril  2016 legacy.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   64582  2 avril  2016 postgis_comments.sql
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  146957  2 avril  2016 postgis_restore.pl
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  149552  2 avril  2016 postgis_upgrade_20_minor.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   69411  2 avril  2016 raster_comments.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    5787  2 avril  2016 rtpostgis_legacy.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  186351  2 avril  2016 rtpostgis.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  204888  2 avril  2016 rtpostgis_upgrade_20_minor.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3593962  2 avril  2016 spatial_ref_sys.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   13756  2 avril  2016 topology_comments.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  271709  2 avril  2016 topology.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  271597  2 avril  2016 topology_upgrade_20_minor.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   14401  2 avril  2016 uninstall_legacy.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   35990  2 avril  2016 uninstall_postgis.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   47073  2 avril  2016 uninstall_rtpostgis.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   10198  2 avril  2016 uninstall_topology.sql
[root@bdx-re-postgres02 lib64]# find / -name postgis
/usr/share/postgis
[root@bdx-re-postgres02 lib64]# ll /usr/lib64/postgis-2.0/
total 5060
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    1239  2 avril  2016 legacy_gist.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    2508  2 avril  2016 legacy_minimal.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   54418  2 avril  2016 legacy.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   64582  2 avril  2016 postgis_comments.sql
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  146957  2 avril  2016 postgis_restore.pl
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  149552  2 avril  2016 postgis_upgrade_20_minor.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   69411  2 avril  2016 raster_comments.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    5787  2 avril  2016 rtpostgis_legacy.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  186351  2 avril  2016 rtpostgis.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  204888  2 avril  2016 rtpostgis_upgrade_20_minor.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3593962  2 avril  2016 spatial_ref_sys.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   13756  2 avril  2016 topology_comments.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  271709  2 avril  2016 topology.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  271597  2 avril  2016 topology_upgrade_20_minor.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   14401  2 avril  2016 uninstall_legacy.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   35990  2 avril  2016 uninstall_postgis.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   47073  2 avril  2016 uninstall_rtpostgis.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   10198  2 avril  2016 uninstall_topology.sql
[root@bdx-re-postgres02 lib64]# ll /lib64/pgsql/
total 1148
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 659728  2 avril  2016 postgis-2.0.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 511528  2 avril  2016 rtpostgis-2.0.so
[root@bdx-re-postgres02 lib64]#
```

[And when I check if postgis is installed in psql, it's the case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSIsZ.png)

But, when I try to activate the extension using `CREATE EXTENSION postgis`, i get an output like this :

```
bash-4.2$ psql
psql (9.2.24, serveur 9.2.18)
Saisissez « help » pour l'aide.

postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
ERREUR:  n'a pas pu accéder au fichier « $libdir/postgis-2.0 » : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
postgres=#
```

Translated from french : `ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.0"` : No such file or directory`

I spend the past 2 days to solve this, but none of the solutions I found worked.

Maybe Postgre is unable to find the correct folder ?

If someone can help me it would be very perfect.

**Edit :**

I found on [this link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-OTHER) that the $libdir can be changed within the postgresql.conf file. But I don't know what to append to the "dynamic_library_path", maybe one of the output of pg_config --pkglibdir ?

Comment: Version 9.2.18? Are you sure you really really want this? Missing 6 long years of patches, EOL for almost 5 years, etc. In what directory did you save postgis and is this Postgis version compatible with PostgreSQL 9.2 ?

Comment: I have to use this version, it's for prod purposes and I don't have the right to change it :/ I know it's stupid but it's part of the obligations pour the infrastrcuture.

For postgis, it's Postgis 2.0.7? It's compatible with Postegres 9.2 because Postgis 2.0.7 acually require Postgres >= 9.2.15 :

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/postgis-2.0.7-2.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not access file "$libdir/plpgsql": No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827761/could-not-access-file-libdir-plpgsql-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Doing "pg_config --pkglibdir" return the following directory : 

/usr/lib64/pgsql

Besides, "which pg_config" return me this folder :

/bin/pg_config

Something's wrong about the location one file ?

Comment: check the owner, some files are root:root

Comment: Ok, I'll check that tomorrow. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @FrankNStein Can you tell me wich ones ? I changed those in /usr/lib64/postgis-2.0 and /usr/lib64/pgsql by doing a chown with postgres user but the error still occur.

Comment: I tried uninstall and reinstall everything with the proper configuration. It really driving me nuts, don't know what to do.