# Populate multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, multidimensional-array, plpgsql

I'm trying populate a multidimensional array on PostgreSQL, but it not work. Below my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION teste()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    tarifas NUMERIC[7][24];
    a INTEGER;
    b INTEGER;

    BEGIN
        FOR a IN 0..6 LOOP
            RAISE NOTICE 'TESTE TESTE %', a;
            FOR b IN 0..23 LOOP
                RAISE NOTICE 'tarifas[%][%] = 0;', a, b;
                tarifas[a][b] = 0;
            END LOOP;
        END LOOP;
    END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Postgres has a dedicated function for that purpose exactly: [**`array_fill()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE):

> returns an array initialized with supplied value and dimensions,
>   optionally with lower bounds other than 1

Use it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION teste()
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
    tarifas numeric[7][24] := array_fill(0, ARRAY[7,24]);
    a int;
    b int;
BEGIN
   -- do something
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### Notes

- Array dimensions in `numeric[7][24]` are just documentation. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-DECLARATION)

> The current implementation does not enforce the declared number of
>   dimensions either. Arrays of a particular element type are all
>   considered to be of the same type, regardless of size or number of
>   dimensions. So, declaring the array size or number of dimensions in
>   `CREATE TABLE` is simply documentation; it does not affect run-time behavior.

- About the assignment operator in plpgsql:  **`:=`** or `=`:

  - [The forgotten assignment operator "=" and the commonplace ":="](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462322/the-forgotten-assignment-operator-and-the-commonplace)
- It's generally not possible to write to an array element directly. You can concatenate or append / prepend elements. Or assign an array as a whole. [Details in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) But a statement like this is *not possible*:

  ```
  tarifas[%][%] = 0
  ```
- Default lower bound of an array is 1, not 0. But you can define arbitrary array dimension. Example:

  ```
  SELECT '[2:3][2:4]={{7,7,7},{7,7,7}}'::int[]
  ```