# How to convert array with non-standard indexes to json?

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I need to convert a `text[]` array not starting from index 1 to json, preserving its indexes.

For example, I have `text[]` array which starts from index 5:

```
select myarr from tbl;

myarr       
-------------------
 [5:5]={blablabla}
```

If I use `array_to_json()` function I get:

```
select array_to_json(myarr) from tbl;

 array_to_json 
---------------
 ["blablabla"]
```

Information about array index has been lost. But I need it.

I need to get it in correct view (for json) which is:

```
[null, null, null, null, "blablabla"]
```

---

PS, I wrapped the given solution in a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_to_json_with_null(myarr text[])
  RETURNS json AS
$func$
BEGIN
   if myarr is null or cardinality(myarr) = 0 then
    return null;
   else
    return array_to_json (array_fill(null::text, 
ARRAY[array_lower(myarr, 1) - 1], ARRAY[1]) || myarr);
   end if;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the Postgres array with NULL values before the conversion. The function [**`array_fill()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) comes in handy for this.

Assuming 1-dimenstional arrays with *positive* array indexes. And data type `text[]` for the array:

```
WITH tbl(arr) AS (SELECT '[5:5]={blablabla}'::text[])
SELECT array_to_json(
            array_fill(NULL::text, ARRAY[array_lower(arr, 1) - 1], ARRAY[1])
         || arr)
FROM   tbl;
```

Related:

- [Normalize array subscripts for 1-dimensional array so they start with 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011569/normalize-array-subscripts-for-1-dimensional-array-so-they-start-with-1)
- [Populate multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22408734/populate-multidimensional-array/22409671#22409671)

#### Function wrapper

Building on the plpgsql function you added to the question. I suggest a simple SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_to_json_with_null_padding(myarr text[])
  RETURNS json AS
$func$
SELECT CASE WHEN cardinality(myarr) > 0
            THEN array_to_json(array_fill(null::text
                                        , ARRAY[array_lower(myarr, 1) - 1]
                                        , '{1}')
                            || myarr)
       END
$func$  LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

Inverting the logic allows a simpler test and no `ELSE` clause, which defaults to `NULL` automatically.

Volatility `STABLE`, because `array_to_json()` is only `STABLE` and not `IMMUTABLE`. This allows **function inlining** - which is also why my function is not `STRICT`). But cannot be used as index expression, which would require `IMMUTABLE`.

Related:

- [Can declaring function volatility IMMUTABLE harm performance?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/212197/3684)
- [Function executes faster without STRICT modifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455177/function-executes-faster-without-strict-modifier)
- [How can I find out if a SQL Function can be inlined?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/212199/3684)