# Casting to a nested type in Postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, types

Is it possible to cast a value to an Array or a Struct with the normal `cast` syntax? For example, similar to how I can do:

```
SELECT 
    '1'::INT, CAST('1' AS INT)
    CAST('1' AS INT)
```

Am I able to do something like:

```
SELECT '[1,2,3]'::ARAY
```

Or:

```
SELECT '{"x":1}'::RECORD
```

To cast something to a nested - and not pre-specified with a previously-created custom `TYPE`?

As an example for comparison, here is using BigQuery:

```
select 
  CAST(([1,2,3],[4,5,6]) AS STRUCT<ARRAY<INT64>, ARRAY<INT64>>) AS a, 
  CAST([1,2,3] AS ARRAY<INT64>) AS b
```

[image]

Comment: Well not `SELECT '[1,2,3]'::ARAY` as there is no `ARAY` type. `SELECT '{1,2,3}'::int[];` would work.

Comment: As to other `select * from  json_each('{"x": 1}'::json);  key | value 
-----+-------` or `select * from  json_to_record('{"x": 1}'::json) as t(x int); x 1`
 x   | 1

Comment: @AdrianKlaver perfect, want to post an answer?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "STRUCT" in Postgres.

To cast to an array, pass typed element values to an [ARRAY constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) (or live with the default element type):

```
SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3];            --> type int[]
SELECT ARRAY[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]];  --> type int[]
```

[Array types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-DECLARATION) can hold any number of nested dimensions, it's still the same *type* on the outside to Postgres.

Or cast an array literal to a specific array type:

```
SELECT '{1,2,3}'::int[];            --> type int[]
SELECT '{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}'::int[];  --> type int[]
```

To form an arbitrary "record", i.e. an anonymous **ROW type**, a.k.a. "composite type", use the [ROW constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS):

```
SELECT ROW('x', 1);  --> anonymous row type
```

(The keyword `ROW` is optional in most contexts.)

But **named** (registered) composite types (ROW types) are more useful in most contexts, as Postgres knows how to properly de-compose it:

```
SELECT ('x', 1)::my_registered_row_type;  --> well-known row type
```

Every table, view, or materialized view in the same database registers a row type implicitly. Or [create a composite type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html) explicitly.

What you show as "RECORD" looks like a JSON value. There are two data types for that in Postgres, [`json` and `jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) ...

Related:

- [Mapping PostgreSQL text[][] type and Java type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743841/mapping-postgresql-text-type-and-java-type/10745524#10745524)
- [Postgres data type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676816/postgres-data-type-cast/13676871#13676871)
- [Populate multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22408734/populate-multidimensional-array/22409671#22409671)
- [Return SETOF rows from PostgreSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864911/return-setof-rows-from-postgresql-function/17865708#17865708)

Answer (score 1):

To cast as an `ARRAY`:

```
SELECT '{1,2,3}'::int[];
 int4   
---------
 {1,2,3}
```

To create an on the fly record:

```
select * from  json_each('{"x": 1}'::json);
 key | value 
-----+-------
 x   | 1
```

To name it:

```
select * from  json_to_record('{"x": 1}'::json) as t(x int);
 x 
---
 1
```