# How to use regex replace in Postgres function?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, plpgsql

I have postgres function in which i am appending values in query such that i have,

```
DECLARE
    clause text = '';
```

after appending i have some thing like,

```
clause = "and name='john' and age='24' and location ='New York';"
```

I append above in where clause of the query i already have. While executing query i am getting "`and`" just after "`where`" result in error

How to use `regex_replace` so that i remove the first "and" from clause before appending it to the query ?

Comment: Have you tried leave `'and'` from the start of `clause`? I don't think manipulating an sql query with regular expressions is a good idea.

Comment: it will append and in query because there are conditions on which it is appending query and it is not possible to stop it thats why after appending i am removing it from clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need regex:

```
clause = substr(clause, 5, 10000);
clause = substr(clause, 5, length(clause)- 4); -- version for formalists
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of fixing `clause` after the fact, you could avoid the problem by using 
[`concat_ws`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) (concatenate with separator):

```
clause = concat_ws(' and ', "name='john'", "age='24'", "location ='New York'")
```

will make `clause` equal to

```
"name='john' and age='24' and location ='New York'"
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be even simpler. Use [**`right()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) with a *negative offset*.

Truncates the first n characters and you don't need to specify the length of the string. Faster, simpler.

Double quotes (`"`) are for identifiers in Postgres (and standard SQL) and incorrect in your example. Enclose **string literals** in single quotes (`'`) and escape single quotes within - or use dollar quoting:
[Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-varchar-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

Since this is a plpgsql assignment, use [the proper **assignment operator `:=`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462322/the-forgotten-assignment-operator-and-the-commonplace). The SQL assignment operator `=` is tolerated, too, but can lead to ambiguity in corner cases.

Finally, you can assign a variable in plpgsql **at declaration time**. Assignments in plpgsql are still cheap but more expensive than in other programming languages.

```
DECLARE
   clause text := right($$and name='john' and age='24' ... $$, -5)
```

All that said, it *seems* like you are trying to work with **dynamic SQL** and starting off on the wrong foot here. If those values can change, rather supply them as *values* with the `USING` clause of `EXECUTE` and be wary of SQL injection. Read some of the related questions and answers on the matter:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[plpgsql]+[dynamic-sql]+EXECUTE+USING

Answer (score 1):

`concat_ws` sounds like the best option, but as a general solution for things like this (or any sort of list with a delimiter) you can use logic like (pseudocode):

```
delim = '';
while (more appendages)
    clause = delim + nextAppendage;
    delim = ' AND ';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with regular expression try this:

```
result = regexp_replace(clause, '^and ', '')
```