# when to use = and := in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, colon-equals

Im using plpgsql to write triggers n Im wondering when to use = and when to use := in postgreSQL, what is the difference???

for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION on_ai_myTable() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
t_ix real;
n int;

BEGIN
IF NEW.time_type = 'Start' THEN
    SELECT t.time_index FROM table_ebscb_spa_log02 t WHERE t.fn_name = NEW.fn_name AND t.time_type = 'Start' ORDER BY t.timestamp02 DESC LIMIT 1 INTO t_ix;
      GET DIAGNOSTICS n = ROW_COUNT;
        IF (n = 0) THEN 
        t_ix = 1;
        ELSE 
        t_ix = t_ix + 1;
        END IF;
END IF;
NEW.time_index = t_ix;
return NEW;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462322/the-forgotten-assignment-operator-and-the-commonplace

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In version 9.4, the documentation was updated to make it clear that there is no difference.

[Version 9.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html):

> 40.5.1. Assignment
>
> An assignment of a value to a PL/pgSQL variable is written as:
>
> variable { := | = } expression;
>
> [...]
>
> **Equal (=) can be used instead of PL/SQL-compliant :=**

In previous versions, `:=` alone was mentioned as the assignment operator, but `=` has been working since the beginning.

Comment: Can we use := for comparisons?

Answer (score 6):

`=` is for comparison. `:=` is for assignment.

Comment: so the example above is incorrect, it should say... IF (n=0) THEN t_ix := 1;  ELSE t_ix := t_ix + 1; END IF; ain't it????

Comment: `=` also works for assignment. Which is a little confusing. Better to stick with `:=`.

Comment: @NickBarnes: `=` for assignment is deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: @a_horse: That's what I thought, but [as of 9.4](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/7e1955b861a1be9ef2dfd6acdd50d0c6b5a75794), it seems that it's officially supported. I agree that it should not be used, though.