# How to pass table name to plpgsql function

Tags: postgresql, function, variables, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to run the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION anly_work_tbls.testfncjh (tablename text) returns int
AS $$
DECLARE 
        counter int;
        rec record;
        tname text;
BEGIN
counter = 0;
tname := tablename; 
FOR rec IN
        select *
        from tname
    loop
        counter = counter + 1;
    end loop;
RETURN counter;
END; 
$$ 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE
SECURITY DEFINER;
```

The goal of this code is to return the number of rows in the table you input.  I know that this might not be the best way to accomplish this task, but the structure of this function would extend nicely to another question I am trying to tackle.  Every time I run the code, I get the error:

```
  ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
```

All online resources I have found tell me how to use the input variable within and `EXECUTE` block, but not in the above situation.

Currently running PostgreSQL 8.2.15.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION anly_work_tbls.testfncjh (tbl regclass, OUT row_ct int) AS
$func$
BEGIN    
   EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) FROM '|| tbl
   INTO row_ct;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Call:

```
SELECT anly_work_tbls.testfncjh('anly_work_tbls.text_tbl');
```

This should work for Postgres 8.2, but you [consider upgrading to a current version](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) anyway.

- I pass the table name as [object identifier type **`regclass`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html), which takes care of quoting automatically and works with schema-qualified names. Details:

  - [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- Using an [`OUT` parameter](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/sql-createfunction.html#AEN47282) simplifies the function.
- Don't quote the language name. It's an identifier.

If you actually need to loop through the result of a dynamic query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION anly_work_tbls.testfncjh (tbl regclass)
  RETURNS int AS
$func$
DECLARE 
   counter int := 0;  -- init at declaration time
   rec record;
BEGIN
   FOR rec IN EXECUTE
      'SELECT * FROM ' || tbl
   LOOP
      counter := counter + 1;  -- placeholder for some serious action
   END LOOP;

   RETURN counter;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE SECURITY DEFINER;
```

- Read this chapter in the manual: [Looping Through Query Results](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING)
- The documented assignment operator in plpgsql is `:=`:

  - [The forgotten assignment operator "=" and the commonplace ":="](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462322/the-forgotten-assignment-operator-and-the-commonplace)

Answer (score 0):

Yes is really not the best way, but this would work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testfncjh (tablename text) returns int
AS $$
DECLARE 
        counter int;
        rec record;        
BEGIN
counter = 0;
FOR rec IN
        EXECUTE 'select * from '||quote_ident(tablename) loop
        counter = counter + 1;
    end loop;
RETURN counter;
END; 
$$ 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE
SECURITY DEFINER;
```

This would be nicer:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testfncjh (tablename text) returns int
AS $$
DECLARE _count INT;
BEGIN    
 EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) FROM '|| quote_ident(tablename) INTO _count;
 RETURN _count;
END; 
$$ 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE
SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful.