# plpgsql function return another function value

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a function `func1()` which returns integer.

I want to write another function `func2(mode integer)` which can return `func1()` reults or do some more stuff. The return value of `func1()` is of type `INTEGER`.

something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func2(mode integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$$
begin
     if mode=1 then
       return func1();  -- NOT plpgsql syntax
     end if;

     more stuff .....

     return 2;
end
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

my question is how to do `return func1();`  ?

I know I can do :

```
select func1() into temp;
return temp;
```

but I was wondring if there is a more elegent way to do that.

Comment: `return func1();` works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/18442/1 What is the error you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these work:

**Option 1:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func2(mode integer)
    RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
    _result integer;
BEGIN
    _result = 2;
     IF mode=1 THEN
       _result = func1();
     END IF;

     --more stuff .....

     RETURN _result;
END
$BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE COST 100;
```

**Option 2:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func2(mode integer)
    RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
     IF mode=1 THEN
       RETURN func1();
     END IF;

     --more stuff .....

     RETURN 2;
END
$BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE COST 100;
```

Comment: Using `:=` as the assignment operator is preferred over the simple `=`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name why is it prefered?

Comment: I never liked the Pascal notation. Just a personal preference :)

Comment: Up until 9.3 this was actually the only documented assignment operator: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-statements.html a simple equal sign was nevertheless accepted.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but if both = and := are acceptable. Why did you say that := is prefered? Prefered for what reason?

Comment: @ban: This related answer provides some background for `=` vs. `:=` in plpgsql: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22001209/939860

Comment: @ban - "=" is logical operator, ":=" is assign statement. Some languages that using "=" for assigning use different symbol for equivalence. PLpgSQL has some limits against origin ADA so this difference doesn't play big role, but better to be consistent with original language - the possibility to use "=" for assignment is bug, but it is too late to fix it.