# Reading pseudo code

Tags: matlab, operators, variable-assignment, pseudocode

So i have been reading this pseudocode which looks like this:

```
%setting up matrix A
    for vertex = 1...n
        a(vertex,vertex) := number of direct neighbors;
        for the direct neighbors of vertex
            if the neighbor is not a pole
                a(vertex,neighbor) := -1;
```

My question is what does `:=` mean here? Is it this?:

```
a(vertex,vertex) = a(vertex,vertex)+number of direct neighbors;
```

or is it this:

```
a(vertex,vertex) = number of direct neighbors;
```

Comment: See this previous question for more than you want to know about `:=`: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344694/what-does-do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344694/what-does-do). Also see this Wikipedia article: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)).

Comment: What does this have to do with MATLAB?

Answer (score 4):

`:=` is traditionally the assignment operator, I don't see where any kind of addition would come from in this case.