# Why we have to use Assignment Expressions in obtaining the return value from await?

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.8

```
import asyncio
from asyncio import StreamReader

async def echo(reader: StreamReader):
    try:
        while data := await reader.readline():
            pass
```

Question> why we have to `data := await` here instead of `data = await`?

> Error from python compiler:
>
> ```
> while data = await reader.readline():
>            ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Comment: Because the [grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) for a `while` says so.

Comment: Note that this is entirely unrelated to ``await``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assignment with `=` was designed expressly to not do this kind of nested side-effecting inside a larger expression. With other languages (looking at you, C) people can type `=` where they meant to use `==` and assign something by accident. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4869770/217324) for more discussion of why `=` was designed this way.

Assignment with `=` is a statement and not an expression, it does not evaluate to what's on the right hand side of the equal sign. That means there isn't a value for the while to test in order to decide whether to continue. The `:=` (AKA the walrus operator) provides a value the while can test, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000198/what-does-colon-equal-in-python-mean).