# fable: list of models to model function

Tags: r, fable-r

With fable I can do:

```r
require(fable)   
it <-  tsibbledata::global_economy %>%    filter(Country == "Italy")
fm <-  model(.data = it, ARIMA(log(GDP) ~ Population), ETS(log(GDP)))
```

I would like to be able to build the model list prior passing it to model(), something like:

```r
mod_list <- list2(m1 = ARIMA(log(GDP) ~ Population), m2 = ETS(log(GDP)))
fm <- model(.data = it, mod_list)
```

I could not find a way of achieving this.
Any suggestions?

Something like:

```r
map(mod_list, model, .data = it)
```

could be a starting point but not exactly what I would like to achieve

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: If there were some data to work with and some `library` calls to load all needed packages then tested code might be forthcoming.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `purrr::imap`.

```
purrr::imap(mod_list, ~fabletools(it, !!.y:= .x))
```

This will return a list of `tsibble::mable` objects. You can then use `purrr::reduce` and `dplyr::left_join` to reduce the the objects into a single mable by joining on the keyed variable in your `tsibble` which is presumably the variable `Country`.

```
purrr::imap(mod_list, ~fabletools(it, !!.y:= .x)) %>%
    purrr::reduce(dplyr::left_join, by = "Country")
```

The double exclamation mark is used to unquote .y (otherwise it would not pass the name from the list) and the `:=` is required to name the variable when programming with tidyverse.

For further info see [What is the R assignment operator := for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32817780/what-is-the-r-assignment-operator-for) and `??imap` in the R help pages.

Comment: More efficient code: 
it %>% fable tools::model(!!!purrr:map(.x = mod_list, .f = function(x) x))
https://community.rstudio.com/t/list-of-models-to-model-function/63191/4