# How to use dplyr quasiquotation in this case?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, quotations

Suppose I have a data frame with column `a` and `b`:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(2,3,4))

  a b
1 2 2
2 3 3
3 4 4
```

Now there are two variables which refer to the column names in the data frame:

```
> col1 <- 'a'
> col2 <- 'b'
```

I want to use these variables to refer to the columns in dyplyr's `mutate` function rather than using the column names directly. The following code works:

```
> df %>% mutate(a=!!sym(col2))
  a b
1 2 2
2 3 3
3 4 4
```

However if I use unquote before the equal sign, it won't work:

```
> df %>% mutate(!!sym(var1) = !!sym(var2))

Error: unexpected '=' in "df %>% mutate(!!sym(var1) ="
```

So how do I make it work in this case? Thanks for any help.

Comment: It should be `df %>% mutate(!!sym(var1) := !!sym(var2))`. You need `:=` if you want to dynamically name the parameter.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks. It works. That was fast! I'll look into the reference question you added.

Comment: That's answered by this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26269423/2372064 It's an operator that R allows (but has no implementation for) and is used most commonly by dplyr and data.table but any package could redefine it. This particular usage would not work with base R functions. It's the "tidyverse" meaning that's used here.