# triple equal sign R

Tags: r, function, symbols, equality

I am trying to create a function that checks for strict equality and I would like to use the triple equal sign. Some context:

```
> 3 == '3'
[1] TRUE
> FALSE == 0
[1] TRUE
```

All of the above check returns `TRUE` because the inputs are coerced to a common type. However I want to check for strict equality. The `identical` function does exactly what I need.

```
> identical(3,'3')
[1] FALSE
> identical(FALSE, 0)
[1] FALSE
```

Now I want to implement this in a more concise and less verbose way. As in Javascript I would like to use the triple equal sign. I wrote this function:

```
`===` <- function(a,b){
  identical(a,b)
}
```

However this doesn't behave as expected:

```
> 3 === 3
Error: unexpected '=' in "3 ==="
```

What am I missing?
Thank you

Comment: I don’t know anything about R but I would guess that its syntax doesn’t allow a `===` operator?

Comment: If you want to create your own infix equality operator, you'll need to use `%%` as Maurits pointed out. The R tokenizer/parser will not recognize symbols not otherwise defined in the language specification.

Comment: @MrFlick Somehow `data.table` managed to define `:=`; I remember reading about this at some point in time but can't remember any details. Do you know how `data.table` goes about defining a new infix(-like?) operator without the `%`s?

Comment: @MauritsEvers That's not quite true. `:=` just happened to already be defined in the parser (a left over operator that was planned to be used but never got a default definition). If they wanted to use anything else, like `~=` or `@=` that would not have been possible. They just got "lucky" there was a left over operator that the parser would recognize. You can't create your own without changing the source code for R itself.

Comment: @MrFlick Interesting. I didn't know that.

Comment: Related to `:=`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269423/why-is-allowed-as-an-infix-operator/26269553#26269553

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define an infix operator (with the `e` in `%e%` for "equal";-):

```
`%e%` <- function(a, b) identical(a, b)
3 %e% 3
#[1] TRUE
```

Or if you want the triple-equal sign as

```
`%===%` <- function(a, b) identical(a, b)
3 %===% 3
#[1] TRUE
```

Or an example with vectors

```
1:3 %===% 1:3
#[1] TRUE
```

These infix operations (where the operator is used *between* the operands) can also be written as

```
`%===%`(1:3, 1:3)
```

in the same way that you can write

```
`==`(3, 3)
```

Comment: I know I could have used percentage signs but it kinda defeats the purpose of typing it fast. At least on my keyboard is shift + 5. I know I could remap the keyboard but it would be an overkill at this point. Is there a way to just use the equal signs?

Comment: @MarcoDeVirgilis I see. No, I don't think you can avoid the `%` signs when using custom infix operators. If you define it as `%e%` at least you'll have the same number of keys as `===`;-)

Comment: @MarcoDeVirgilis Perhaps interesting in the wider context: [Why was % chosen as the operator delimiter](https://community.rstudio.com/t/why-was-chosen-as-the-operator-delimiter/3309)